# Adding custom icon doesn't work in Leaflet?

Tags: leaflet, javascript, cordova

I'm trying to add custom icon to a map. All seems ok but when I click to add markers on my map I get the Leaflet icon by default and not the one I liked to have. Perhaps is in the way I get the `IconUrl` from a JSON or something else but I don't see where.

```
            displayMarkersByCat(offersFromCat,iconMarkers);
            console.log(offersFromCat);
            offersFromCat = [];
            displayIconByCAt(iconUrl);
            console.log(iconUrl);
            iconUrl = [];
        }); 
    }); 
}

function displayIconByCAt(iconUrl) {
    console.log(iconUrl);

    var data = iconUrl.toString(data);
    console.log(data);
    createNewicon(data);   
}

function createNewicon(data){
    console.log(data);
    var iconMarkers =  new L.icon({
        iconUrl: data, // value of the URL img by cate
        iconSize: [38, 38], // size of the icon
        iconAnchor: [22, 94], // point of the icon which will correspond to marker's location
        popupAnchor: [-3, -76] // point from which the popup should open relative to the iconAncho  
    })  
    console.log({iconMarkers});
}

function displayMarkersByCat(offersFromCat,iconMarkers) {
    console.log(offersFromCat);
    console.log(data);
    // resetInterface();

    var markers =  new L.layerGroup();
    for (var i = 0; i < offersFromCat.length; i++) {
        var data = offersFromCat;

        console.log(data[i]);
        console.log(data[i][0]);
        marker = new L.marker([data[i][0], data[i][1]]).bindPopup(data[i][2]);

        markers.addLayer(marker,{icon : iconMarkers}).addTo(mymap);
        console.log(markers);
    }
    mymap.addLayer(markers);
}
```

And when I init my map for the first time I have static markers wich work well

```
var gastro = L.icon({
    iconUrl: 'www/images/alimentation.png',
    iconSize: [38, 38], // size of the icon

    iconAnchor: [22, 94], // point of the icon which will correspond to marker's location

    popupAnchor: [-3, -76] // point from which the popup should open relative to the iconAnchor

});
console.log(gastro);
var markerGastro = L.marker([43.6490449,
    0.5885573000000477], { icon: gastro }).addTo(mymap);

markerGastro.bindPopup("<b></b><br>I am a popup.").openPopup();
```

I just thinking it's where is the problem , my markers have been created already ????

Comment: Can you give an example it this `iconUrl`? And statement `var data = iconUrl.toString(data);` is definitely wrong. Method `toString(n)` is used to convert number to string using radix `n`.

Comment: index.js:71 ["www/images/alimentation.png"] = iconUrl ;
index.js:74 www/images/alimentation.png = data ;
index.js:79 www/images/alimentation.png; 
Perhaps I just have to keep my first value of IconUrl ?;

Comment: Can you explain what statement `var data = iconUrl.toString(data);` is supposed to do? What is content of ` iconUrl` and what should be content of `data` at the end?

Comment: I'm using this function because I get the URL of my image icon from iconURL wich is a string in a array. So I used toString to covert this array in a single string to push it into the IconUrl of leaflet icon object. But perhaps I'm not using the good way to do it ?

Comment: Then just use `var data = iconUrl[0]`.

Comment: doesn't work any more but aafetera lot of console.log in my code, I think that my new ICON is OK and it' s more a problem with my markers group